# Passing multidimensional array using Serializable

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I have passed one multi-dimensional array to another activity using putSerializable() and retrieve using getSerializable. But I got some problems. Please help me to solve my problem..

First activity:

```
  String [][] selected_list= new String[10][];           
  Bundle list_bundle=new Bundle();
  list_bundle.putSerializable("lists",selected_list);

  Intent list_intent= new Intent(v.getContext(), second_activity.class);
  list_intent.putExtras(list_bundle);
  startActivityForResult(list_intent, 2);
```

Second Activity:

```
  String [][] list_new= new String[10][];    
  Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
  Serializable list= b.getSerializable("list");
  list_new=(String[][])list;
```

When I am running my application, my application is suddenly stopped.
Is this the right method to retrive the String array?
Please give me the solution..
Thank you...

---

This is the output from Debug window:

> CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>   CalorieCounter [Android Application]
>       DalvikVM[localhost:8605]
>           Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
>               ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2663
>               ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679
>               ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
>               ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033
>               ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
>               Looper.loop() line: 123 
>               ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627
>               Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
>               Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
>               ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
>               ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
>               NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
>           Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
>           Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
>           Thread [<7> Binder Thread #3] (Running)

Comment: If it is stopped, then there should be a stack trace in your android logcat. Please, show it.

Comment: CalorieCounter [Android Application] 
 DalvikVM[localhost:8605] 
  Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
   ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2663 
   ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679 
   ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
   ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033 
   ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99

Comment: Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
   Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
   ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868 
   ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
   NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method] 
  Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
  Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
  Thread [<7> Binder Thread #3] (Running)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use serializable, android implements parcelables in a much much more effective way. The catch is you have to define how parcel the object yourself, but it really isnt that hard.

Simple example:

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

To send it:

```
Intent list_intent= new Intent(v.getContext(), second_activity.class);
list_intent.putExtras("list",list_bundle);
startActivityForResult(list_intent, 2);
```

To recieve it:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
MyParcelable list= (MyParcelable)b.getParcelable("list");
```